# Why modern Google chrome/Edge browsers print the value of undeclared JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log(aName);
var aName = 'Martin';
```

I tried to execute this JS code in latest Google chrome and Edge browsers. It printed name value. i.e. 'Martin'. I got little confused here, because of JavaScript hoisting. According to hoisting only declarations are hoisted and not initialization. Since it is 'var', it should throw undefined error as per my assumption. But, when I tried with IE-11 browser, it worked as expected and threw undefined error. What is going here?

Comment: It's called [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) and it's been doing this in all browsers since, well forever

Comment: You sure about that? Just tried it in chrome console and it printed `undefined` as expected. Of course, if you execute this snippet again in the same console, it will print `Martin`, as the assignment is still valid.

Comment: Just plugged your code example into Chrome console and got "undefined" - Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Are you sure you're not running the snippet twice?

Comment: I created a fiddle and it produces "undefined" - (https://jsfiddle.net/8phao6dy/)

Comment: `name` may be `window.name` and already initialised. I made you a snippet with `aName` instead

Comment: Thanks to all of your commented answers here. Yes, I think, I have probably executed the script twice in the same console. That's why, it was giving weird, unexpected answer.